# Does a 100 Hour Inspection Start Over Every Annual?

Tags: faa-regulations, airworthiness

If an airplane receives a 100 hour at 350 hours and has an annual at 400 hours, does the next 100 hour inspection need to take place at 450 hours or 500 hours?

Comment: Are you asking about FAA regulations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The annual will reset the 100 hours.

See [91.409](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=1&SID=1454781a31ab227ba05604c523261622&ty=HTML&h=L&mc=true&r=SECTION&n=se14.2.91_1409)

> (b) Except as provided in paragraph (c) of this section, no person may operate an aircraft carrying any person (other than a crewmember) for hire, and no person may give flight instruction for hire in an aircraft which that person provides, unless within the preceding 100 hours of time in service the aircraft has **received an annual or 100-hour inspection** and been approved for return to service in accordance with part 43 of this chapter or has received an inspection for the issuance of an airworthiness certificate in accordance with part 21 of this chapter. The 100-hour limitation may be exceeded by not more than 10 hours while en route to reach a place where the inspection can be done. The excess time used to reach a place where the inspection can be done must be included in computing the next 100 hours of time in service.

Comment: It is also worth nothing that [the requirements (14 CFR 43 Appendix D)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=95fad5c1003a8390de20d39927b2dc07&mc=true&node=ap14.1.43_117.d&rgn=div9) for an Annual inspection include those requirements for a 100 hr inspection.